# How to install Debian on a loopback device?

Tags: debian, system-installation

I'd like to install Debian on a loopback device (`/dev/loop0`).

I can easily access the command prompt by booting off the DVD and asking for a shell, and I'm assuming it should also be easy to mount the loopback device on `/`.

The part that I don't know is: how do I manually run the installer, after I have mounted `/`?

Comment: The regular installer already does this but doesn't require the target directory to be the root directory. Examine the `debian-installer` sources.

Answer (score 3):

Debian installs into /target by default.  You will have to skip some of the install steps and have a file ready for loopback mounting.  Run mkfs.ext2 (or similar) on the file before mounting -o loop.

```
mkdir /target
mount /path/to/file /target -o loop
```

Normally, with special purpose installs, I skip the debian installer and use debootstrap and apt:

```
debootstrap wheezy /target http://debmirror/debian
mount -bind /dev /target/dev
''      ''  /proc  ''
''      ''  /sys   ''
''      ''  /dev/pts /target/dev/pts
chroot /target
apt-get install linux-image grub

... the remainder depends on how you want to deploy the image
(setup grub and linux with debconf)(remember no mbr on fs image)
(edit /etc/fstab)
```